# Do I have to use Bundle for data exchange between activity and fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

Multiple Fragments are created in one Activity to switch pages to Fragment binding. At this point, the data in Main Activity must be used by all fragments.

So I did it like this.
I called method in Activity that return data in activity.
↓ fragment.java

```
MainActivity main = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    data = main.getCurrentUserID();
```

And this is getCurrentUserID() in MainActivity.

```
public String getCurrentUserID() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    String curUser = intent.getStringExtra("USER ID");
    return curUser;
}
```

This way, no data is loaded. Why is that? How can I take out items in one Bundle from multiple fragments to use Bundle?

Comment: you haven't posted anything in here leads me to believe you've assigned a value to a bundle or assigned that bundle to a fragment or an activity

Comment: your getCurrentUserID() function is invalid. You are just creating a new Intent then trying to get string extra. If you are trying to get activitiy's intent you can use this.getIntent()